# Why move all objects when press 'G' key

Tags: objects, selection-tools, object-mode, select

I definitely chose one object and I don't know why it's all moving together. I want to move one object, and I never set up a parent.

[image]

Comment: because you've enabled the Proportional Editing option (blue circle icon on the middle of the top header)

Comment: There must be duplicates of this but the question is always different

Comment: @Jackdaw I think so. It's hard to find the right case because things are different even if I try to find one.

Comment: @moonboots What circumstances do you usually use the Proportional Editing feature?

Comment: usually in Edit mode when you want to smoothly deform the shape of an object, you move a vertex and the other ones follow...

Comment: @moonboots Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have accidentally manage to enable Proportional Editing.
Toggle it with "O" key or click this button.

[image]